# how do I set up a image upload to a folder that the folder name is a value of another field in the model in DJango

Tags: django

I have a model with some fields:

```
class RankStructure(models.Model):
    RankID = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    SName = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    LongName = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    GENRE_CHOICES = (
        ('TOS', 'TOS'),
        ('TMP', 'TMP'),
        ('TNG', 'TNG'),
        ('DS9', 'DS9'),
        ('VOY', 'VOY'),
        ('KTM', 'KTM')
    )
    Genre = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='RANKS/'+<<GENRE>>+'/', blank=True)
```

In the last line is an image FileField.  I want the folder to be associated with the Genre.  So if the Genra is `TOS`, then the folder should be `RANKS/TOS/image.jpg`.

How do I set it so this happens?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom upload handler.

```
def image_upload_handler(instance, filename):
    return 'RANKS/{genre}/{filename}'.format(
        genre=instance.genre,
        filename=filename
    )

class RankStructure(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_handler, blank=True)
```

Also I recommend using this for image fields: https://github.com/edoburu/django-any-imagefield

Comment: Thank you so much. I like the recommendation.  I'm a bit confused on what django-any-imagefield would give me further.  Thank you.

Comment: It will give you nice previews in admin using the image backend that you have installed automatically. Basically just an extension of ImageField.

Comment: Thanks much.  I'll give it a shot.